# What is IList used for?

Tags: c#

I have already searched for it on MSDN and I read the definition that it is a non generic ....
but my problem is that i am not understanding what is its use and when to use it . So i hope that anyone can help me . Thanks .

Comment: There is a generic list found in System.Collections.Generic - It is an interface used by classes such as List

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the older code that doesn't know about generics, there are also a lot of cases where you know you have a *list* of data, but you can't know *of what* ahead of time. Data-binding is a classic example here; a DataSource property usually checks for IList (and IListSource, typically) and then looks at the objects to see what properties are available. It can't use generics in this case.

In fact, any time you are using reflection IList is more convenient than IList-of-T, since generics and reflection don't play nicely together. It can be done, but it is a pain. Unfortunately since IList-of-T doesn't derive from IList there are cases where this can fail - but it is a good 95% rule.

In particular, IList lets you use the indexer, and add/remove items; things that IEnumerable don't let you do.

Most app-level code (i.e. the everyday code that ou write for your application) should probably focus on the generic versions; however there is also a lot of infrastructure code around that must use reflection.

Comment: Many of those reflection scenarios become quite a bit easier(but sometimes slower too) with `dynamic`. So the pain should be a bit smaller in .net 4.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - well, it won't help with things like per-type properties, but yes: finding an Add method might be easier. There is a complication though that dynamic can't see explicit implementations, so something can implement IList and IList-of-T and yet still be completely unusable from dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

`IList` (non-generic version) is a leftover from C# version one, when we didn't have generics.

With C# 2 and .NET Framework 2.0, generics was added to the language and generic implementations of the collection types was added. Therefore, the non-generic versions was no longer needed, but they couldn't be removed from the framework, since it would make porting code from .NET 1.1 to 2.0 a pain.

Today, you almost always use `IList<T>`, the primary reason for `IList` to still be around is for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Sorry, but even now there are plenty of uses for **library** code to use IList (non-generic). Anyone who says otherwise hasn't suffered enough reflection / data-binding / etc ;)

Comment: but yes; most app-level code should use the generic versions; just remember there is lots of infrastructure code that doesn't know about your types and can't possibly use generics.

Comment: @Marc, I agree on those points - there are use cases when you need the non-generic version. I tried to indicate that with the words _you almost always use_ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is an interface that existed *before* generics were introduced in .NET 2.0.

It is there for backwards compatibility.

Use the generic version.

Answer (score 1):

it is a interface , which is normally implemented by collection classes which is intended to provide list like method but in .net version less than 2.0 i.e. without generic introduction so if you are using framework version 1.0, 1.1 than you would see the usage of this IList